# How to limit memory of a OS X program? ulimit -v neither -m are working

Tags: macos, memory, virtual, launchd, ulimit

My programs run out of memory like half of the time I run them. Under Linux I can set a hard limit to the available memory using ulimit -v mem-in-kbytes. Actually, I use ulimit -S -v mem-in-kbytes, so I get a proper memory allocation problem in the program and I can abort.

But... ulimit is not working in OSX 10.6. I've tried with -s and -m options, and they are not working.

In 2008 there was some discussion about the same issue in [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=573616), but nobody proposed a good alternative. The should be a way a program can learn it's spending too much memory, or setting a limit through the OS.

Comment: To add to this, I don't seem to be able to make it work with `setrlimit` either, with any of RLIMIT_RSS, RLIMIT_DATA, RLIMIT_AS or (reaching here) RLIMIT_STACK.

Comment: As it stands, the bounty will be unawarded.

Answer (score 8):

You can't.  Apple can (using the `ledger()` system call, which is private), but you can't.  I'm not entirely sure whether launchd's options work or not - certainly if it was still using the code visible in the last open source version (from 10.9.5), it wouldn't, because it calls `setrlimit()`, but it's been substantially rewritten since then, though I can't see it calling `ledger()`, which I'd expect it to if this was supposed to work.

Why? Because the `RLIMIT_DATA` and `RLIMIT_AS` options to `setrlimit()` don't actually *do* anything in current versions of XNU (the macOS kernel).

Comment: Is this still the case? Is there a place I can find out more? It seems like your answer is the most recent piece of information regarding memory limits for processes on osx in the whole internet

Answer (score 6):

After struggling with this myself (with limited success), I have determined there seems to be two ways to do it...

You can setup a launchd item for your executable.. The important part of the plist is a section, such as..

```
<key>SoftResourceLimits</key>
<dict>
    <key>Stack</key>
    <integer>10000000000</integer>
</dict>
```

There are various keys available...  which can be found on **[Apple's MAN page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html)**.

Another way to do it, *I think*, is by setting a value in either **/etc/launchd.conf** (system) or **/etc/launchd-usr.conf** (peruser).  For example, your launchd.conf could contain...

```
umask 002
limit stack 67104768 67104768
limit maxproc 3400 4500
limit maxfiles 256 unlimited
setenv PATH /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

The documentation for all of launchd's functionality is shotty, if you ask me.. It's as if Apple might not care / want people outside their walls to actually understand how it all works.  [There is so much power](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20050620071558293) to be had by mastering launchd and it's intricacies... but there are few concrete/official resources available as to how to properly implement them.

Comment: +1 I am up against launchd, and I can't let go of it.  If it just worked in any consistent way, i would use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

[`setrlimit`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setrlimit.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/setrlimit) should do the job. I believe that's the BSD equivalent of `ulimit`...

Comment: I looked at the man page for `setrlimit`, and couldn't see how to set a limit on virtual memory, though you can set a limit on physical memory.

Comment: I know bash ulimit is implemented directly calling setrlimit. In Linux man page there is the option RLIMIT_AS, that limits "the maximum size of the process’s virtual memory (address space) in bytes", that is what I want to control. I really don't care about the limit of physical memory. I want to know when the whole program is over 2Gb.

Well, on OS X manpage for setrlimit, there is RLIMIT_AS. The nearest is RLIMIT_RSS.

Indeed, IMHO OS X seems to allocate a lot of virtual memory, given what I see in the Activity Monitor.

Comment: Mmm... SUSv3 demands `RLIMIT_AS`, (see http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrlimit.html) and OS X sells as an SUSv3 UNIX, so it should support `RLIMIT_AS`. Indeed `<sys/resource.h>` defines `RLIMIT_AS`, although it's not mentioned in the man page. Could you try   `RLIMIT_AS` to see if it's really implemented?

Comment: It seems I should try... Thanks.

Comment: There are varied reports on the Internet that `setrlimit` is just plain broken on Darwin (OS X).  http://lists.apple.com/archives/Unix-porting/2007/Apr/msg00026.html

Comment: See also the feature matrix in [Section 7.11 of APUE](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch07lev1sec11.html) -- it says clearly that limiting memory is not supported on OS X (at least not in 10.3, have to check current edition). Limiting virtual memory is supported in OS X, though...