# How can I run a process with a hard memory limit on OS X?

Tags: macos, memory, profiling, low-level

I'm implementing an algorithm that needs to run under a hard memory limit of 4MB.

Is there a way to run a process in a way that it would get killed if it over-reaches its memory limit? Or simply just profile its allocations to be able to see how much maximum memory has been allocated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think ulimit is what you're looking for:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/ulimit.3.html

Ulimit don't work all the time though, and alternative ways of limiting a process system resources is mentioned here:
[How to limit memory of a OS X program? ulimit -v neither -m are working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274385/how-to-limit-memory-of-a-os-x-program-ulimit-v-neither-m-are-working)

Also the same question has been asked here, so this question might bring some enlightenment on the problem, especially concerning virtual memory:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43371/way-to-limit-how-much-ram-an-arbitrary-process-can-take-up

You will probably get a hard limit by following this tip thou, together with the use of ulimit:
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=201106020948369

Answer (score -2):

Look at this to install coretools with brew:
    [Timeout Command on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504945/timeout-command-on-max-os-x)
then use gtimeout -m 4096 myscript

Comment: `gtimeout` doesn't seem to have an `-m` flag